# Can we have an out of class definition for a class template that is a member of a class template

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, class-template

I know that the following snippet is valid:

```
template<typename T>
struct Custom 
{
    template<typename V> void func();
};

//valid
template<typename T> 
template<typename V>
void Custom<T>::func()
{
    
}
```

But can we do the same for a *class template* instead of a *member function template*. Take for example,

```
template<typename T>
struct Custom 
{   //declaration here
    template<typename V> struct InnerCustom;
};

//can we define the class template `InnerCustom` outside?
template<typename T> 
template<typename V>
Custom<T>::InnerCustom
{
    
};
```

My question is that can we have an out of class definition for the class template member `InnerCustom` just like we had for the member function template `func`? If so, how can i do that. Also, **if** not what is the reason for this difference.

Comment: Just add `struct` before `Custom`. [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/uZvg_71Wm).

Comment: Yes, it's allowed. See [this example](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.class#general-example-2) (the last one, i.e. `S::inner`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can make an out of class definition for `InnerCustom`:

```cpp
template <typename T>
template <typename V>
struct Custom<T>::InnerCustom { // note: `struct` added
    // ...
};
```